# jQuery Live Search with Quicksilver Style in a Multi Select List Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get John Resig's [jQuery Live Search with Quicksilver Style](http://ejohn.org/apps/livesearch/) to work with a select multi form control. His code is based  [John Nunemaker's Work](http://orderedlist.com/articles/live-search-with-quicksilver-style-for-jquery/) developing his [quicksilver.js](http://orderedlist.com/demos/quicksilverjs/javascripts/quicksilver.js) code.

The problem I am having is that within a select box only Firefox supports .hide() on option values, I can't figure out a snappy approach for IE, Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Here is an example, I have inlined John R's code but you will need to grab [quicksilver.js](http://orderedlist.com/demos/quicksilverjs/javascripts/quicksilver.js) and host it locally yourself. Again this works great in Firefox but the call to rows.hide() does nothing on other browsers.

I have tried wrapping the  tags in in a div and hiding that but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>LiveSearch</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/quicksilver.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#q').liveUpdate('#posts').focus();
     });

     jQuery.fn.liveUpdate = function(list){
       list = jQuery(list);

       if ( list.length ) {
           // Changed 'li' to 'option' below
           var rows = list.children('option'),
              cache = rows.map(function(){
              return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
              });

           this
               .keyup(filter).keyup()
               .parents('form').submit(function(){
                   return false;
               });
       }

       return this;

       function filter(){
           var term = jQuery.trim( jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase() ), scores = [];

           if ( !term ) {
               rows.show();
           } else {
               rows.hide();

               cache.each(function(i){
                   var score = this.score(term);
                   if (score > 0) { scores.push([score, i]); }
               });

               jQuery.each(scores.sort(function(a, b){return b[0] - a[0];}), function(){
                   jQuery(rows[ this[1] ]).show();
               });
           }
       }
     };

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" autocomplete="off" action="">

  <div>
     <input type="text" value="" name="q" id="q"><br><br>

     <select id="posts" multiple name="choices" SIZE="10" style="width: 250px">
        <option value="1">The Well-Designed Web</option>
        <option value="2">Welcome John Nunemaker</option>
        <option value="3">Sidebar Creative: The Next Steps</option>
        <option value="4">The Web/Desktop Divide</option>
        <option value="5">2007 in Review</option>
        <option value="6">Don't Complicate the Solution</option>
        <option value="7">Blog to Business</option>
        <option value="8">Single Line CSS</option>
        <option value="9">The Great Divide</option>
        <option value="10">What's in a Name?</option>
     </select>

  </div>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So basically, you're looking for a cross-browser way to hide options?

Comment: Yes, so far it only works in Firefox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach is just to add and remove options from the DOM.

Like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#q').liveUpdate('#posts').focus();
     });

     jQuery.fn.liveUpdate = function(list){
       list = jQuery(list);

       if ( list.length ) {
               // Changed 'li' to 'option' below
               var rows = list.children('option'),
                  cache = rows.map(function(){
                  return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
                  });

               var all = rows;
               all.each(function(i){
                  $(this).attr("itext", this.innerHTML.toLowerCase());
               });

               this
                       .keyup(filter).keyup()
                       .parents('form').submit(function(){
                               return false;
                       });
       }

       return this;

       function filter(){
               var term = jQuery.trim( jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase() ), scores = [];

               if ( !term ) {
                       list.append(all);
               } else {
                       rows.remove();

                       all.each(function(i){
                               var score = $(this).attr("itext").score(term);
                               if (score > 0) { scores.push([score, i]); }
                       });

                       jQuery.each(scores.sort(function(a, b){return b[0] - a[0];}), function(){
                               list.append(all[this[1]]);
                       });

                       rows = list.children('option');
               }
       }
     };

  </script>
```

**EDIT:**

Need to score over array "all" rather than rows.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you - I had been banging my head against the desk.

Comment: One followup issue, anyone know a good way to add a delay so if a user types several keys rapidly it does not call filter every keyup? At a couple thousand options it can get pretty slow.

Comment: You should create a new question for that, but in short you can use javascript's builtin setTimeout/clearTimeout methods to add a delay before filtering.